# How to split a string and repeat characters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm trying to convert the `array = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]` into `array = ["A", "BB", "CCC", "DDDD"]`. If you compared the arrays, you'll notice that the letters inside the second array have extra same letters in each position. Here is my code below. I used the for loop because I wanted to use the increment inside the for loop. I don't even know if map() method can do the same so I went with for loop. However, when I checked, it didn't show the result that I wanted. What did I miss?

```js
function accum(s) {
  // your code
  let accArray = s.toUpperCase().split("");

  for (let i = 1; i < accArray.length; i++) {
    accArray[i].repeat(i + 1);
  }

  console.log(accArray);
}
accum("abcd")
```

Comment: Strings (and all primitives) are immutable. For string sin particular methods like `repeat` and `replace`, etc., return a *new* string with the modified value, the original string remains unchanged.

Comment: @VLAZ Oh right! I completely forgot that `repeat` returns a new string. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @VLAZ Why did you mark my question as duplicate? I looked at the other question and it doesn't answer my question. The other question was talking about substr() method while I was asking about repeat() method and map() method.

Comment: String are immutable. Any method that "changes" a string actually returns a new string - `repeat`, `replace`, `substr`, `slice`, `toUpperCase`, and so on and so forth. None of these will change the string they are called on - there is no need to write the same answer for each of these methods when the answer is the same - you have to call the method and assign the value somewhere.

Comment: @VLAZ true that strings are immutable. However, the other question was mostly talking about the solutions and using substr(), slice(), etc. In fact, the other question is a broad question. The quote you mentioned was only one paragraph in the best solution. My question was specific and narrowed to map() and repeat() methods. That is what is different from the other question.

Answer (score 3):

A more concise way to achieve the desired output is to use [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
const accum = (s) => s.toUpperCase()
                      .split("")
                      .map((s, i) => s.repeat(i + 1));
                      
console.log(accum("abcd"));
```

Answer (score 2):

[**`String.prototype.repeat()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

> The `repeat()` method constructs and ***returns*** a new string which contains the specified number of copies of the string on which it was called, concatenated together.

You have to assign the new ***returned*** value at the specific *index*:

```
accArray[i] = accArray[i].repeat(i + 1);
```

```js
function accum(s) {
  // your code
  let accArray = s.toUpperCase().split("");

  for (let i = 1; i < accArray.length; i++) {
    accArray[i] = accArray[i].repeat(i + 1);
  }

  console.log(accArray);
}
accum("abcd")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to push values to array, or assign back to that index, `repeat` does not mutate the original value it returns a new string [`Repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) so you need to assign it back

```js
function accum(s) {
  // your code
  let accArray = s.toUpperCase().split("");
  let op = []
  for (let i = 0; i < accArray.length; i++) {
    op.push(accArray[i].repeat(i + 1));
  }

  console.log(op);
}
accum("abcd")
```

Comment: I find Mamun's answer to be better, the reason being, that answer utilises existing variables instead of creating a new one.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt i follow rule to not mutate my variables as until unless there a need to, so i used a different variable

Answer (score 1):

if your input is already an array like

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

then you can use

```
arr.map((item, idx) => item.repeat(idx+1))
```

if you are having string like

```
str = 'abcd'
```

then you can use:

```
str.split('').map((item, idx) => item.repeat(idx+1);
```

Comment: Obviously you can do the upperCase or lowerCase to string before passing through the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` or `map` both work perfectly as iterator

```js
function accum(s) {
  // your code
  let accArray = s.toUpperCase().split("");
  const arr = [];
  accArray.forEach((e, index) => {
    arr.push(e.repeat(index + 1))
  })

  console.log(arr);
}
accum("abcd")
```